# Managed object context not being passed correct, array is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to move my process to the background thread, but i believe the managedObjectContext is not being passed correctly. Initialize it in the background queue of the location manager, as so:

```
managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.managedObjectContext.parentContext = moc;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]){
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];



    NSNumber *nsInterval = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"location_interval"];
    interval = (nsInterval == nil) ? -1 : [nsInterval intValue];

bgBackupHandler = [[BackgroundBackupHandler alloc]init];
bgBackupHandler.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

I then call it in another method in the location handler class as so:

```
[bgBackupHandler OnSyncComplete:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] message:@"BG-Backup Called"];
```

Then in the bgBackupHandler class everything works up until i try to fetch. The array is always null. I think im not passing my managedObjectContext correctly. Ive tried using self.managedObjectContext but the code either crashes or, the array is still null. What is the difference between self.managedObjectContext and just simply managedObjectContext. Ive also read some where it is strictly forbidden to pass a managedObject from one MOC to the other.

The work is all being done in the background.

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"bdir_0001" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", strDirName];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: Your `BackgroundBackupHandler` class has a `managedObjectContext` property, and yet when you make the request, you use `managedObjectContext` on its own, without referring to the property.  Where is that variable defined?

Comment: Is the fetch being done in the background enclosed within a `performBlock:` ?

Comment: @avi the variable is a property in the interface and synthesized in the implementation section.

Comment: @quellish it is being called by a listener function

Answer (score 0):

Core Data allows for two different concurrency models: thread confinement, which is deprecated, and queue confinement. When an `NSManagedObjectContext` is created with the initializer `initWithConcurrencyType:` it uses queue confinement.

Queue confinement requires the application to follow a set of simple rules. Access to any of the non thread safe methods or properties of the context and it's objects must be done through the `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` methods. The only safe methods are the read-only accessors of the context and the context's property setters. All other methods of the `NSManagedObject` context and the `NSManagedObject`s it owns must be accessed through these methods.

In your case, the fetch you are performing must be done in a block passed to one of these methods. For example:

```
[managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = nil;

    array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}];
```

It a good idea while developing to enable Core Data concurrency debugging assertions to catch these and other issues. When an application is passed the `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug` argument on launch Core Data will halt execution when it runs into a concurrency issue like violating the rules described above. This helps to catch issues early in your development cycle.